# Excel: Substracting time into negative

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have times entered in an Excel sheet:

```
A1:  08:00
A2:  07:00
A3:  =A2-A1
```

I expect to see "-01:00" as the result, but I get "##############"
For positive results it works.

What do I have to do to get negative hours?

EDIT 1:
There must be an easy solution without cascading formulas, etc.
I just found a Worksheet in the internet where it seems to work (Cell K10):

[image: Formula in Cell K10]

The user defined formatting for K10 is not very special:   *[hh]:mm;[Red]- [hh]:mm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses the `TEXT` function:

```
=IF(A2<A1, TEXT(ABS(A2-A1), "-h:mm:ss"), TEXT(ABS(A2-A1), "h:mm:ss"))
```

This is a well known problem in Excel, q.v. the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182247).

Comment: There is an easier way (provided in your link): switching to 1904-Dates.